# How To Compile Wami Recorder In Windows

Tags: apache-flex, compiler-construction, mxml

Hello everyone i am trying to compile the wami recorder using flex but i receive two errors -->[image]

I downloaded the src from this url http://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/source/browse/ and made no changes, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue and finally got it to work using this command line:

> mxmlc -compiler.source-path=C:\wami\src -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true c:\wami\src\edu\mit\csail\wami\client\Wami.mxml -output C:\wami\src\edu\mit\csail\wami\test.swf

Hopefully it helps for you too

Answer (score 0):

You download the source code into the wrong directory; making Flex think that a class is in the wrong location.  Since you didn't specify a source path; Flex is probably assuming that C:\ is the root of your source.  So, try specifying a source path.  Probably something like this:

```
mxmlc Wani.mxml -source-path "C:\edu\mit\csail\wami\client"
```

More information about [Flex Compiler options](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_01.html).

Comment: i tried the following line but i receive the error "command line: Error: unable to open 'C:\edu\mit\csail\wami\client\"' "

Comment: i also tried copying the wami directory to the bin directory of the flex but i receive the same error with my original post

Comment: ok i removed the equal sign and i receive " Error: unable to open 'Wami.mxml' "

Comment: i found this page http://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/wiki/GettingStarted , but i still cant make it work